# How to find a matching object in two generic arrays by attribute name?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a generic abstract class which contains two generic arrays:

```
export abstract class DataProvider<V, T extends {token:string}> {
  inputA: T[] = []; 
  result: V[] = [];
}
```

I want to provide a function where you can pass in an attribute name which should be present in `T` AND `V` (and somehow should also have the correct type).
The function then should find the item with this attributename and the same value in both arrays and retrieve the token and return a message.

This is how far I got:

```
 public generateMessagesByAttribute<K extends keyof V & keyof T>(attributeName: K): SuccessMessage[] {
  const successMessages: SuccessMessage[] = [];
  this.result.forEach(item => {
    const index = this.inputA.findIndex(input => input[attributeName] === item[attributeName]); // here is the error
    if (index !== -1) {
      successMessages.push({
        taskToken: this.inputA[index].token,
        output: JSON.stringify(item),
      });
    }
  });
  return successMessages;
}
```

However I receive this error:
 `The comparison appears to be unintentional because because the types U[K] and V[K] have no overlaps`
Which I do not understand since I clearly specify `K extends keyof U & keyof V`.

Furthermore this does not look very typesafe since even though the attribute name could be present in both arrays they could have different types. How can I meddle this also in?

[TSPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

[Update] One solution suggested was to extend the type of `inputA` to `(T&V)[]`. However that would mean that `inputA` would contain all props from `T` and `V` which is not what I want. However I could somehow make the type of `inputA` more specific in that sense that it has to have one attribute which has to be in `T` and `V`.
But I am not sure if this is possible when this attribute is passed in in the constructor of the class and therefore during runtime.

Comment: I just had a few minutes to look at it but it looks like exactly what I need but give me some time to understand it ;) I will have a look at it tomorrow

Comment: yes that was what I was looking for, but tbh I do not understand it fully Especially the `this:` part in the function confuses me. why is that needed?

Comment: so since `DataProvider<V, T extends { token: string }>` is more constraint than `DataProvider<T | V, { token: string } & (T | V)>` there is no issue I assume but I do not understand why this is needed

Comment: no I will accept it, I just thought my thoughts might help you with your answer that's all.

Comment: Okay I wrote up an answer; the `this:` part is not *needed*, but it helps with widening `input`/`item`.  There are multiple ways to do that and my answer shows several

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are having is because, in the implementation of `generateMessagesByAttribute()`, it really is true that `input` is of type `T` and `item` is of type `V`, and the compiler has no idea if `T[K]` and `V[K]` are comparable to each other.  TypeScript only wants to allow `input[k] === item[k]` if the types are "related" in some way.  The easiest way to work around this is to widen either `input` or `item` to `(T | V)` before comparing:

```
input[attributeName] === (item as T | V)[attributeName] // okay
```

There are other more heavyweight approaches, such as widening `this` to something like `DataProvider<T | V, T>`, which will have the effect of `input` being of type `T | V` from the beginning:

```
const thiz: DataProvider<V | T, T> = this; // widen
thiz.result.forEach(item => {
  const index = this.inputA.findIndex(input =>
    input[attributeName] === item[attributeName] // okay
  );
  if (index !== -1) {
    successMessages.push({
      taskToken: this.inputA[index].token,
      output: JSON.stringify(item),
    });
  }
});
```

Or you could put this constraint directly on `this` by specifying a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters): so that the function can't even be called unless the object can be appropriately widened:

```
public generateMessagesByAttribute<K extends keyof T & keyof U>(
  this: DataProvider<V | T, T>,
  attributeName: K
): any[] {
  const successMessages: any[] = [];
  this.result.forEach(item => {
    const index = this.inputA.findIndex(input =>
      input[attributeName] === item[attributeName] // okay
    );
    if (index !== -1) {
      successMessages.push({
        taskToken: this.inputA[index].token,
        output: JSON.stringify(item),
      });
    }
  });
  return successMessages;
}
```

Any of those should work, and probably others as well.

---

But that doesn't necessarily solve the full problem; even though the *implementation* has no compiler error, presumably you want to prevent *callers* from calling `generateMessagesByAttribute()` on a key unless that keys types are at least somewhat compatible with each other.  For that you can [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `K` to not just `keyof T & keyof V` (equivalent to `keyof (T | V)`), but to just the subset of those where `T[K]` and `V[K]` overlap.  That is, where `T[K] & V[K]` are not `never`:

```
type OverlappingKeys<T, U> =
  { [K in keyof (T | U)]: T[K] & U[K] extends never ? never : K }[keyof (T | U)]
```

And you can see how it works:

```
interface Vee {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  c: string;
  d: "abc";
}
interface Tee {
  a: string;
  b: boolean;
  c: "abc";
  d: string;
  token: string;
}
type VeeTeeOverlap = OverlappingKeys<Tee, Vee>;
// type VeeTeeOverlap = "a" | "c" | "d"

declare const dp: DataProvider<Vee, Tee>;
dp.generateMessagesByAttribute("a"); // okay, both string
dp.generateMessagesByAttribute("token"); // error
dp.generateMessagesByAttribute("b"); // error, no overlap between boolean and number
dp.generateMessagesByAttribute("c"); // okay, overlapping types
dp.generateMessagesByAttribute("d"); // okay, overlapping types
```

Looks good.  In the above, `"b"` is not acceptable because you'd be comparing a `number` to a `boolean`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=5.3.2#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gbhATgGwIZjASwHYHMDSEIAzgDwAqANFAKoB8UAvAFBRQDeUA2vlDlAGsiAewBmUABTkoAH1oBKALoAuKOR6KoAMloaoEAB7AI2ACbEo2CAkRQA-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-aes9qDZEaj8PAmdIDEFPufEql8h432QWPcuB8M7VEwZ-HBzV8FTHykAA)

Comment: thank you for that perfect explanation! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
export class DataProvider<V, T extends {token:string}> {
    inputA: (T & V)[] = []; // inputA extends T & V
    result: V[] = [];

    public generateMessagesByAttribute<K extends keyof T & keyof V>(attributeName: K): SuccessMessage[] {
    const successMessages: SuccessMessage[] = [];
    this.result.forEach(item => {
        const index = this.inputA.findIndex(input => input[attributeName] === item[attributeName]); // here is the error
        if (index !== -1) {
        successMessages.push({
            taskToken: this.inputA[index].token,
            output: JSON.stringify(item),
        });
        }
    });
    return successMessages;
    }
}

const dp = new DataProvider<{
    key: true
    key2: boolean
}, {
    key: false
    other: boolean
    token: ""
}>()
```

Comment: While this might solve the problem an it's usually a good idea to *explain* what you did and why.

Comment: ah ok, but that means `key` can have any type and there could be a type mismatch rignt?

Comment: and doesn't this mean that the items of `inputA` need to have all props from V and T ?